# How to publish Shiny App from R Server to Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny

I have 2 servers installed on Ubuntu server:

1. R Server serverip:8787
2. Shiny Server serverip:3838

Is there a way to publish Siny App directly from Rstudio Server without using terminal?

For example by saving the app from R Studio directly to a specific folder and then linking this folder to Shiny Server as a source folder.
How can I do it?

Comment: Did you check this link: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html

Comment: You could edit Shiny server files on R server, just mount as decribed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/410588/how-to-mount-a-directory-from-another-server)